# How do you get MS-Word to always open to the last page of a multi-page document? The document is a daily journal

Tags: microsoft-word, open, page

Not much to include here, I simply want my Word document to always open to the last page of the document so I can pick-up where I last left-off.  The document is a daily journal.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the document to `.docm` for macro support? ([link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-make-a-multi-page-word-2010-document/1f91eac0-c3c7-41ef-9706-9d9058034359)).

Answer (score 2):

You can  press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> after opening the document to move to the last editing position.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t appear to be possible to open at the end, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will get you there in one keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a Word document AND go to the end of that document and then close it, this action will be saved in the Registry at:`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Reading Locations\` (notice the '16.0' version of mine) where Word saves the HEX representation of the viewed paragraph and the (probable) combination of the position of the clicked character in relation to the total occurrence of the same. So, since Word 2013, as soon as you reopen this file, Word will show a popUp inviting you to pick up where you left off. Very useful for continuing reading or editing. If you don't want to do this, just ignore this popUp, which automatically disappears in a few seconds. See [this article](https://df-stream.com/2014/01/ms-word-2013-reading-locations/) and [this other](https://thinkdfir.com/2019/02/11/microsoft-office-reading-locations-part-1/).